# How to get Inkscape to save PDF's without ugly black boxes behind transparent raster images

Tags: pdf, inkscape

I am using the vector graphics editing program Inkscape. Whenever I use File -> Save A Copy -> PDF, if there are any raster images with transparency in my document, the transparent areas will save with black boxes behind them instead of being transparent.

[image: screenshot of problem]

It appears that this is an Inkscape Bug. There is a bug report from 2009 on the issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/381677). (Yiiikes. 2009? Uuugh!)

I have found one workaround to the problem that I have posted in [this thread](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=25092) on the Inkscape forum.

However I wanted to see if the SuperUser community could:

1. Provide more information on this bug (does it only affect certain users, such as Windows 7 users?) and
2. If there any better workarounds (the workaround I link converts the image to raster, losing all vectors).

Answer (score 4):

Ungrouping the images in question a couple of times, until the status bar said "image" instead of "group of 1 object", fixed the problem. Some of the empty groups had mask and clip effects applied to them, and the stacking of these effects is what caused the bug. The groups/effects can be safely removed without distorting the images.

Apparently PDF's imported into Inkscape can often have large stacks of useless groups in them, and this can trigger the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a .svg pic that I draw myself. The solution was to import it as a .png, instead of a .pdf or .svg. In addition, I was able to keep a very good resolution and dramatically reduced its size.